# IEEEtran bibliography -- “germanify” it

Tags: bibtex, languages, ieeetran

For a paper at university we have to use the IEEE style -- which can be done using IEEEtran LaTeX file. What we also have to take care of, though, is that the bibliography is German as well.

Using

```
\bibliography{./FrontBackMatter/WissenschaftlichesArbeiten_3D_-_Drucker}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

for the bibliography, I get entries like

```
J. F. Kelly and P. Hood-Daniel, Printing in Plastic: Build Your Own 3D Printer, 1st ed. Apress, Jun. 2011.
```

and

```
H.-J. Warnecke, E. Westkämper, and M. Decker, Einführung in die Fertigungstechnik, 7th ed. Wiesbaden: B. G. Teubner Verlag / GWV Fachverlage GmbH, 2006.
```

However, I need the edition to be in German -- “Auflage”, as well as the connector between authors (“und” instead of “and”). Additionally, website titles are in English double quotes (“…”) and I would like them to be in German („…“). 
It would also be nice if I could save the effort of putting words that start with an uppercase letter in {} to have them printed starting with uppercase letters. Right now, for example the second book’s bibtex entry looks like this:

```
  @book{warnecke_einfuhrung_2006,
    address = {Wiesbaden},
    edition = {7},
    title = {{E}inführung in die {F}ertigungstechnik},
    isbn = {978-3-8351-0110-4},
    lccn = {{32ZHU1750(7)}},
    language = {Deutsch},
    publisher = {B. G. Teubner Verlag / {GWV} Fachverlage {GmbH}},
    author = {Warnecke, Hans-Jürgen and Westkämper, Engelbert and Decker, Markus},
    year = {2006}
}
```

So I always have to change the files manually after exporting my bibliography out of Zotero (the organising tool I use).

EDIT:
Here is a mwe:

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass[10pt,compsoc, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
Of course this isn’t an actual quote but I’m going to use cite anyway.\cite{kelly_printing_2011}
Awesome, right?\cite{warnecke_einfuhrung_2006},\cite{schnitker_stereolithographie_2008}
\bibliography{example}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\end{document}
```

With (example) bibfile entries:

```
@book{kelly_printing_2011,
    edition = {1},
    title = {Printing in Plastic: Build Your Own {3D} Printer},
    isbn = {978-1430234432},
    abstract = {Printing in Plastic: Build Your Own {3D} Printer is your gateway into the exciting world of personal fabrication. The “printer” that you’ll build from this book is a personal fabricator capable of creating small parts and other objects from drops of molten plastic. Design a part using a modeling tool such as Google {SketchUp.} Then, watch while the fabricator head sweeps back and forth and upwards, depositing plastic in all the right places. You can build anything from a replacement tab to hold a bookshelf in place, to a small art project, to a bashguard for your bicycle. If you can conceive it and design it, you can build it, and you’ll have fun doing it!},
    language = {English},
    publisher = {Apress},
    author = {Kelly, James Floyd and Hood-Daniel, Patrick},
    month = jun,
    year = {2011}
},
@book{warnecke_einfuhrung_2006,
    address = {Wiesbaden},
    edition = {7},
    title = {{E}inführung in die {F}ertigungstechnik},
    isbn = {978-3-8351-0110-4},
    lccn = {{32ZHU1750(7)}},
    language = {Deutsch},
    publisher = {B. G. Teubner Verlag / {GWV} Fachverlage {GmbH}},
    author = {Warnecke, Hans-Jürgen and Westkämper, Engelbert and Decker, Markus},
    year = {2006}
},

@book{schnitker_stereolithographie_2008,
    address = {München},
    title = {{S}tereolithographie – das bekannteste {V}erfahren des {R}apid {P}rototyping},
    isbn = {978364056960-1},
    location = {V146092},
    url = {http://www.grin.com/de/e-book/146092/stereolithographie-das-bekannteste-verfahren-des-rapid-prototyping},
    language = {Deutsch},
    publisher = {{GRIN} Verlag {GmbH}},
    author = {Schnitker, Marc},
    year = {2008},
    keywords = {Lasersintern, Rapid prototyping, {RP}, Stereolithographie}
}
```

Full bibliography (so far): [bibliography](http://pastie.org/private/fismcy9sn7sr9z44tk2oq)

Comment: Something seems to be incorrect with the quotes usage (Anführungszeichen) in IEEEtran-de, in the actual entry, they appear after the colon, like "xxxxx," Not an actual answer, I can see that, but how do you post in comments ?

Comment: @user27146 I don’t exactly understand your comment. In German, the comma is set after the quotation marks—which are „…“, not "…", by the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try the `IEEEtran-de.bst` from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/Bibliography/german/ 
You have a lot of urls the reason why I prefer to set the bibliography ragged right. My example file which now has no problem with your bib data:

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass[10pt,compsoc, a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\begin{document}
Of course this isn’t an actual quote but I’m going to use cite anyway.\cite{kelly_printing_2011}
Awesome, right?\cite{warnecke_einfuhrung_2006},\cite{schnitker_stereolithographie_2008}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran-de}
\begingroup
\RaggedRight
\bibliography{foo2}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

However, some urls are still problematic, you have to add some more possible breakpoints. See documentation for package `url` or search here.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but where do I put it? Somewhere within the depths of the LaTeX installation or in my working folder.

Comment: for the first try put it into your main documents folder and in your TeX source use `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtrn-de}`

Comment: It’s better than the standard IEEE style but there are still some awkward things. For example: it says “Aufl.” but uses English counters (1st, 2nd, n'th). Also, without interfering manually German titles of, say, books are still printed in lowercase letters (except for the first word)

Comment: can all be changed. Will do it in the afternoon.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu: I edited the bst file. Try again with the new version.

Comment: With the new version I ran into a problem: http://pastie.org/private/nq31w2f41dehv6oumvktrw

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6729/discussion-between-pattafeufeu-and-herbert)

Comment: add that bib entry to your above example or put the complete bib anywhere for downloading.

Comment: I added it to the question and also to the chat

Comment: Don't forget to update the changelog in the style. Otherwise, +1 for rewriting a bibtex style file for a user :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot. I will have a look at what is different in your bibtex style file vs the original one to be able to understand what magic foo happened there.

Comment: @ Herbert: thx a lot for the provided deIEEEtran.bst!

Comment: can someone provide the IEEEtran-de, which @Herbert has mentioned. The link: http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/BibTeX/ doesn´t work. Thanks.

Comment: The link to `IEEEtran-de.bst` is dead (see Marek's answer below), could you update it?

Comment: http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/Bibliography/german/

Comment: All links seem dead now.

Comment: Note, that the links are still printed with the english prefix "Available:" instead of "Verfügbar:". 
Also the d of "Ph. D. dissertation" is lower case and should be upper case in German.